# Is there a way to pass parameters to Thymeleaf includes?

Tags: thymeleaf

So I have the following views:

```
<body>
<!--@thymesVar id="repidTable" type="biz.tugay.RepidTypeTable"-->
<div th:include="repidTable"></div>
</body>
```

and **repidTable.html** is as follows:

```
<!--@thymesVar id="repidTypeColumns" type="java.util.List<biz.tugay.RepidTypeTableColumn>"-->
<!--@thymesVar id="repidTypeRows" type="java.util.List<biz.tugay.RepidTypeTableRow>"-->
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th th:each="repidTypeColumn : ${repidTypeColumns}" th:text="${repidTypeColumn.columnHeaderText}">
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr th:each="repidTypeRow : ${repidTypeRows}">
        <td th:each="repidTypeCell : ${repidTypeRow.repidTypeTableCells}" th:text="${repidTypeCell.data}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

which works fine.. However, I want to be able pass parameters to **repidTable**.

What I need is, instead of **repidTable.html** something like **genericTable.html** which will accept 2 parameters, and I would like to pass repidTypeColumns and repidTypeRows while including **genericTable.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this was quite easy. I have the following file **messageFile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Repid Type POC</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--@thymesVar id="messageObject" type="biz.tugay.Message"-->
<div th:fragment="messageDiv(messageObject)">
    <span th:text="${messageObject.getMessageBody()}"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Repid Type POC</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--@thymesVar id="successMessage" type="biz.tugay.Message"-->
<!--@thymesVar id="errorMessage" type="biz.tugay.Message"-->
<div th:include="messageFile :: messageDiv(${successMessage})"></div>
<div th:include="messageFile :: messageDiv(${errorMessage})"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller is like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String foo(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("successMessage", new SuccessMessage());
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", new ErrorMessage());
        return "index";
    }
}
```