# Send only <Form> tag block from thymeleaf template

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am super new to thymeleaf. This is my HTML template which is used. But on some occasions, I only need the  block to send to other ends without sending the whole HTML template. Is there a way to get only the form fragment? Thanks in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <title>LTI Launch</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="prepage">
            <form th:action="${url}" th:method="${method}" id="blti-link-view">
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried HTML fragments but to set attributes

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

had to put. So when I try to get only the fragment above HTML block came along.

I need to get only a form block and send it as a response without sending the whole html block.

Comment: yes, you could create a html fragment with only the form code and then include on the pages where you are interested

Comment: @cralfaro could you please read the question again. I updated the question.

Comment: In that case as you only need that block of html with different object or url I would go for creating a method in your controller and only return that html template, and you could call it via ajax from your page

Comment: Thank you @cralfaro could you please provide some documentation link to pass attributes to a block of Html?

Comment: Yes you can check this sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774928/is-there-a-way-to-pass-parameters-to-thymeleaf-includes